# ui-grid ng-style dynamic height

Tags: height, ui-grid, ng-style

I got a simple grid used like this :

```
 <div id="planningGridDiv" 
    class="gridPatientContent"

    style="height: 450px;min-height: 300px;"

    ng-style="{height: showScores ? '150px': '450px'}"

    ui-grid-resize-columns
    ui-grid-selection
    ui-grid-cellNav
    ui-grid-pinning

    ui-grid="myData"
    class="grid">

  </div>
```

But when showScores is true and height pass from 450 to 150 px, the grid itself doesn't shrink.

The first container see its height changed, but this part no :

```
<div role="grid" ui-grid-one-bind-id-grid="'grid-container'" class="ui-grid-render-container ng-isolate-scope ui-grid-render-container-body" ng-style="{ 'margin-left': colContainer.getMargin('left') + 'px', 'margin-right': colContainer.getMargin('right') + 'px' }" ui-grid-render-container="" container-id="'body'" col-container-name="'body'" row-container-name="'body'" bind-scroll-horizontal="true" bind-scroll-vertical="true" enable-horizontal-scrollbar="grid.options.enableHorizontalScrollbar" enable-vertical-scrollbar="grid.options.enableVerticalScrollbar" aria-multiselectable="true" id="1490734763451-grid-container" style="margin-left: 180px; margin-right: 80px;">
```

I can't find any solution on doc nor stack overflow, but it seems to me that it should. I can use some help for some pointers.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, I found a solution on another stackoverflow question, but I changed it a bit to fit my needs :

```
 $scope.showScoreDiv = function()
{
    $scope.showScores = !$scope.showScores;

    $timeout(function(){
         $scope.gridApi.grid.handleWindowResize();
    }, 1); 
};
```

So the main idea is to change the height via ng-style on the grid div, and when you fire your event, here `showScores = true` called by `showScoreDiv()`, you have to call  `gridApi.grid.handleWindowResize()`.
The timeout is just here to give some time to the div to be set to the good height before calling `handleWindowResize()`.